# In sbt, how do you add a plugin that's in the local filesystem?

Tags: scala, sbt

If I want to add a plugin that's in a local directory outside the project tree, what's the right way to do that?  Say I clone something simple like https://github.com/steppenwells/sbt-sh.git to /tmp/sbt-sh - what do I put in my build.sbt file to use the plugin from /tmp/sbt-sh that will pick up any changes I make in /tmp/sbt-sh?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this in `project/project/Build.scala` should do it:

```
import sbt._
object PluginDef extends Build {
    lazy val projects = Seq(root)
    lazy val root = Project("plugins", file(".")) dependsOn( shPlugin )
    lazy val shPlugin = uri("file:///tmp/sbt-sh")
}
```

Note that that the doubly-nested `project` directories are required. I'm not aware of any way to do this from an `.sbt` file (there may be a way, but I don't know what it is).

This is documented [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Plugins.html#1d%29+Project+dependency) (see "1d) Project dependency").

Comment: Thanks.  I saw that but it didn't occur to me that you could just use a file:// url.  Seems like there should be a more straightforward way to do this though, something like addLocalSbtPlugin("/tmp/sbtsh")

Comment: This might work too (I've not tried it):

lazy val shPlugin = file("/tmp/sbt-sh")

Comment: Also, the error message you get if you put in the wrong filename is a bit misleading: Invalid build URI (no handler available): file:///tmp/sbt-shX/ (where sbt-shX doesn't exist)

Comment: And yes, your file() suggestion works: lazy val webPlugin = file("/tmp/sbt-sh")

Answer (score 13):

In 0.13, there's a) a simple way to do this, and b) better documentation.  @PaulButcher's answer pointed to [section 1d of the sbt documentation for plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Extending/Plugins), which now tells you to edit project/plugins.sbt:

Up to 0.13.0:

(@axel22 points out this has changed, so check the current doc before you copy this)

```
lazy val root = project.in( file(".") ).dependsOn( assemblyPlugin )
lazy val assemblyPlugin = uri("git://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#0.9.1")
```

And of course that uri(... can be replaced with a file("/tmp/sbt-sh").

**Update:**

[After sbt 0.13.0](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/commit/4a08b65cb26aafe143f271da27048cc0cd70f0b4) you'll need to wrap the uri or file with `RootProject`. I.e.,

```
lazy val root = project.in( file(".") ).dependsOn( assemblyPlugin )
lazy val assemblyPlugin = RootProject(file("lib/sbt-sh"))
```

Comment: `RootProject` is missing in the second line.

Comment: @axel22 That's a later addition; 0.13 didn't use it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - I had only tried with 1.0+.

Comment: do you put this in build.sbt? or plugins.sbt?