# How to use in my own project a forked SBT plugin

Tags: sbt

These are the steps I've followed:

- I have forked a 3rd party plugin.
- I have modified it, and run `sbt publishLocal` successfully.
- In order to test it, in the `plugins.sbt` file of a project, I've changed `addSbtPlugin("company" % "some-plugin" % "0.6.5")` to this:

  lazy val root = project.in( file(".") ).dependsOn(somePlugin)

  lazy val somePlugin = project.in(file(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/customPath/"))

but `SBT` cannot compile the plugin in this way, because it doesn't find the used plugins of the plugin, even though I've been able to .

I've tried also to reference `~/.sbt/local/....`, i.e., the directory where `publishLocal` has placed the compiled plugin, but no success.  I don't know what do I have to reference exactly (the folder, the generated `.jar`, the `ivy.xml` file, ...).

Questions:

- What is the best way of using a locally built plugin?.
- Why does it compile alone, but doesn't when embedded in my project?.

Notes:

- This question is closely related to this one: [In sbt, how do you add a plugin that's in the local filesystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568821/in-sbt-how-do-you-add-a-plugin-thats-in-the-local-filesystem/23172218#comment44801788_23172218)
- I'm using SBT 0.13.7.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple.  I've followed this steps:

- I fork an existing project
- I change the `organization` in order to be unique, and not to clash with the original author.  I use something like `organization := com.github.myuser`
- I modify the code
- I create an account in `bintray`, and follow [this guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Bintray-For-Plugins.html) in order to publish my custom plugin with `sbt publish`
- In a sample project, I import my custom plugin, by adding this line in `plugins.sbt`: `addSbtPlugin("com.github.myuser" % "myplugin" % "1.0")`
- If I make a mistake and don't want to increase the version, I make this:

  sbt ;bintray::unpublish;publish

It is very fast, I've had to wait a few seconds.  I know nobody else is using my plugin.

Maybe `publishLocal` is better and doesn't require to work with 3rd party repositories, but I don't know how it works.  This works for me instead.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution, well suited when the only intention is to test a future **pull request**:

- Fork an existing project
- Change the version to end with -SNAPSHOT
- Make your changes
- Invoke `sbt publishLocal`
- Create a sample project in order to test it, that references the -SNAPSHOT version
- In case of recompiling again the project, `reload` hangs the whole JVM.  I have to exit `SBT` and enter again.
- When working, make a `pull request` to the author.

**Suggestion**: use the [scripted test framework](http://eed3si9n.com/testing-sbt-plugins) in order to leave a working test.